# Getting Posted Videos with Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am learning to use the Facebook API and am trying to create a quick app that once you log in you see a list of videos and links that were posted in your stream for the last few days.

My code is available here: https://github.com/lem72/Facebook-API-Test/blob/master/index.php and you can see it in action here: http://www.elitebeat.com

I have two questions/problems:

1. It seems to load very slowly and was wondering if I am doing something wrong or if I could do something better to make it load faster?
2. I try to get all the posts from the last 3 days (eventually I will make this user specified), but it seems very random at how far back the content goes.  Am I doing something wrong here, or is this a limitation of the FB Graph api?

I am fairly new to programming and brand new to GRAPH API so thank you for your patience.

Comment: Also is there a better way to just grab videos posted in your feed?